# Setting a global variable inside a method

Tags: ios, swift

```
//Global variable:
var senderString = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
...
set()
print(senderString)
}

func set() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{
        logout()
    } else{
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.senderString = dic["username"] as! String
                print("this"+self.senderString)
            }
            })
    }

}
```

How do i set the global variable senderString to dic["username"] as! String ? I want the senderString global variable to reflect the username.

Comment: use `var senderString`

Comment: @CoderFrom94 It is var, it got crop out

Comment: Then this should be working fine, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @CoderFrom94 When i print(senderString) in viewdidload it is getting nil. However,in the method when i print ("this..") it is giving me the username. Thus,i think i did something wrongly.

Comment: is it nil or is it ""? I am pretty sure it will be an empty string rather than username

Comment: @CoderFrom94 Emptystring

Comment: You're running into this issue, because `observeSingleEvent` is an asynchronous method, so you're trying to access the return value from it before a value would be assigned.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Got it thks